# TFS 2012 cannot connect to SCVMM 2012

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

The TFS server and scvmm server can ping success to each other. But we can't configure the Lab Management of TFS to the scvmm. It throws the following exception:

[image: tfs connects to scvmm exception]

The tfs and scvmm all run in the same domain and related services run as the same domain account.

More info:

1. SCVMM console on TFS server cannot connect the sc server with the following error:
   [image]
2. SCVMM console on scvmm server can successfully connect to scam server locally
3. List item

Could you give me some clue about the issue?

Version:

1. TFS server  is 2012
2. Scvmm server is 2012 SP1
3. Scvmm console on tfs server is 2012
4. Scvmm console on scvmm server is 2012 sp1

Comment: Sill not sure the issue. Today I have tried that we can't add host in the same data center to SCVMM 2012 too. Maybe it caused by physical device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of investigation, the issue is cased by the Scvmm console version.
SCVMM console must be the same version as SCVMM server.

In order to integrate TFS with SCVMM:

1. Install the SCVMM console on TFS server
2. The SCVMM console version should be same as the version of SCVMM server

Now we setup an SCVMM 2012 server, use the SCVMM 2012 console on TFS to connect to the SCVMM 2012 server successful.